# Rails to pass :datetime attribute from model to model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

I tried to make a topic has a :datetime attribute so that I am able to show latest discussed topic on top of topic index page. The :datetime was determined by its post

The relation are as following

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :topic
end
```

I have tried to make @topic.updated_at = @post.updated_at
but it seems not work.
So I add a new attribute disscuss_time: to topic model and make topic model like following:

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts

  before_save :default_values

  def default_values
    self.discuss_time ||= self.updated_at
  end
end
```

And in my post_controller

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
 def create  
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
    @topic.discuss_time = @post.updated_at
 end
```

The Post.new is in Topic controller

And make the view like

```
     <% topics.order("discuss_time desc").each do |f| %>
```

It is not work. Although the post is showed on topic's show page, in my admin page the diss_time is empty. And in topic's index page, everything is in its default order. How to pass the :datetime attribute form model to model?

There is another way, which is to make the topic updated while topic.post.count changed. But this way seems still have some problem.

Comment: Is the updated `@topic` actually being saved? And make sure `@post.updated_at` has a value.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, after_add: :touch
end
```

This creates a callback on the `posts` association which calls [touch](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-touch) (which updates the created_at timestamp to the current time).

If you really need the time to be EXACTLY the same as the posts created_at you can instead do:

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, after_add: :update_ts!

  def update_ts(post)
    self.update_attribute(:created_at, post.created_at)
  end
end
```

You don't need to do anything special in the controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
   def create  
      @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
      @post = @topic.posts.new(topic_params)
      # ...
   end
end
```